# Is there a way to send a thumbnail to the printer LCD screen when printing over USB from OctoPrint?

Tags: marlin, octoprint, usb, mriscoc, octopi

I'm using Cura Thumbnails using a plugin in Cura 5.5. Also, I use the Marlin-based mriscoc firmware on a Creality Ender 3 V2 with OctoPrint using OctoPi on a Raspberry Pi 4.

The firmware supposedly supports Thumbnail's preview when printed from an SD card, although I never tried. I can also view the Thumbnail in the OctoPrint UI. I print only using USB, controlled by OctoPrint on my Raspberry Pi.

Is it possible to send the Thumbnail to the printer LCD when a print is started from OctoPrint? In a similar way to how I have to add 'Show Progress on printer LCD' using a Cura plugin to follow the progress on the printer LCD when OctoPrint controls it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is currently not possible to see the thumbnail in the printer screen if the G-code is being printed from a host like Octoprint. It is technically possible if the same G-code exists on the SD card or if the user can wait about 5 to 10 minutes for the binary jpeg image to be transferred to the SD card using the serial protocol. But I don't think it's worth the effort.

Comment: What if we develop a OctoPrint plugin that after a file upload to the Pi, checks the file for thumbnails, adds the thumbnail to the SD card and the firmware picks it up? Or will the 'upload to sd' be equally slow as what you have mentioned?

Comment: It is technically possible; You can try it using Marlin BFT, but the time consumed by image transfer could worsen the user experience.